# How to set current page with Yii2 ActiveDataProvider?

Tags: yii2

How to set current page with Yii2 ActiveDataProvider
Yii 1.1 in set above method:

```
'pagination'=>array(
  'pageSize'=>2,
  'currentPage'=>1,
),
```

Answer (score 6):

In Yii2 you can use the property `page` of the `pagination` obj as described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$page-detail):

In your DataProvider set

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Product::find(),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 2,
            'page' => 0
        ]
    ]);

$model = $dataProvider->getModels(); //Models in page 0
$dataProvider->pagination->page = 1; //Set page 1
$model = $dataProvider->refresh(); //Refresh models
$model = $dataProvider->getModels(); //Models in page 1
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy (and dumb way) I believe is to put before you load everything into the model something like

```
$_GET['page'] = $_GET['page'] ? $_GET['page'] : 2;
```

This would get pick up by the active date provider and use page 2 as the default page.

Or you can just make the list go to the second page directly by linking to the second page directly

```
echo Url::to(['post/index', 'page' => 2])
```